# Как получить ID пригласившего в беседу?

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

```
vk.updates.on(['chat_invite_user'], async (ctx) => {
console.log(`ID: ${???}`)
)}
```

Приведённый выше код реагирует на приглашение пользователя в беседу. Я не совсем понимаю, как можно получить ID того, кто пригласил. Мне нужно получить ID именно из этого события, а не messages.getConversationMembers, Т.К. бот должен работать без каких-либо прав в беседе. На форуме есть ответы, но они относятся к другим библиотекам и языкам. Пишу на node.js + vk-io.
[image: Поле, которое мне необходимо получить]

Comment: а что приходит в `ctx`?

Comment: Спасибо огромное за пинок! console.log(context.payload.message) выдаёт объект {date: 1603488589, from_id: 576684166, id: 0, out: 0, peer_id: 2000000095, …}
с необходимым мне полем  "from_id".